# Which drivers should I install for my AMD graphics card?

Tags: drivers, ati, 15.10, radeon

In the history of me having this machine, I've successfully been able to get a stable installation of Linux on my computer one time. All other times, either I did something stupid when I was playing around, or it was a graphics driver problem.

I've installed the beta versions of both the Ubuntu-specific and generic Linux AMD Catalyst drivers, as well as just used the recommended AMD-compatible drivers given to me by the OS in Settings, and many times I'll restart and the graphics will crash and I'll be sent to a TTY. From here, I attempt to revert my changes and undo the damage, but sometimes different people's advice ends up making it worse.

So...I'm asking the community. Based on the hardware specs I have below, is there a specific process that any of you would recommend for me to get the correct drivers installed and operational?

Honestly at this point, I'm really wanting as specific of instructions as I can get because I'm frustrated at this whole process.

Hardware specs:

---

FROM LSHW

---

H/W path         Device     Class          Description

======================================================

/0                          bus            Motherboard

/0/0                        memory         7867MiB System memory

/0/1                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz

/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller

/0/100/1                    bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port

/0/100/1.1                  bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port

/0/100/1.1/0                display        Tahiti LE [Radeon HD 7870 XT]

/0/100/1.1/0.1              multimedia     Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]

/0/100/2                    display        Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller

/0/100/14                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/14/0      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/14/1      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/14/1/1               input          Razer BlackWidow Ultimate 2013

/0/100/14/1/2               input          Razer DeathAdder Chroma

/0/100/16                   communication  7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1

/0/100/1a                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2

/0/100/1a/1      usb5       bus            EHCI Host Controller

/0/100/1a/1/1               bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub

/0/100/1b                   multimedia     7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller

/0/100/1c                   bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1

/0/100/1c.3                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4

/0/100/1c.3/0               storage        ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller

/0/100/1c.4                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5

/0/100/1c.4/0    enp5s0     network        NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe

/0/100/1c.5                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6

/0/100/1c.5/0               bridge         ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge

/0/100/1c.7                 bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8

/0/100/1c.7/0               bus            ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller

/0/100/1c.7/0/0  usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/1c.7/0/1  usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/1d                   bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1

/0/100/1d/1      usb6       bus            EHCI Host Controller

/0/100/1d/1/1               bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub

/0/100/1f                   bridge         Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller

/0/100/1f.2                 storage        7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]

/0/100/1f.3                 bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller

/0/2             scsi0      storage

/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           120GB Samsung SSD 840

/0/2/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1  volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume

/0/2/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         127MiB reserved partition

/0/2/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3  volume         111GiB Windows NTFS volume

/0/2/0.0.0/4     /dev/sda4  volume         449MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/3             scsi1      storage

/0/3/0.0.0       /dev/sdb   disk           1TB WDC WD1002FAEX-0

/0/3/0.0.0/1     /dev/sdb1  volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/4             scsi2      storage

/0/4/0.0.0       /dev/sdc   disk           1TB WDC WD10JPVX-22J

/0/4/0.0.0/1     /dev/sdc1  volume         511MiB Windows FAT volume

/0/4/0.0.0/2     /dev/sdc2  volume         927GiB EXT4 volume

/0/4/0.0.0/3     /dev/sdc3  volume         3681MiB Linux swap volume

NOTE: I'm not sure why it's listing two models of Radeon, but I have the 7870.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is your GPU, the second is the HDMI audio output. I have the same card.
I recently switched to the opensource radeonsi drivers and they work quite ok.

A complete install instruction you find in the wiki:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver